# find indices of ndarray compared with ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have two unsorted ndarrays with the following structure:

```
a1 = np.array([0,4,2,3],[0,2,5,6],[2,3,7,4],[6,0,9,8],[9,0,6,7])
a2 = np.array([3,4,2],[0,6,9])
```

I would like to find all the indices of a1, where each a2 row is in a1 and also inside a1 the position:

```
result = [[0,[3,1,2]],[2,[1,3,0]],[3,[1,0,2]],[4,[1,2,0]]
```

In this example a2[0] is in a1 at position 0 and 2 within a1 position at 3,1,2 and 1,3,0. For a2[1] at position 3 and 4 within a1 position at 1,0,2 and 1,2,0.

Each a2 row appears twice in a1. a1 has a least 1Mio. rows, a2 around 10,000. So the algorithm should be also quite fast (if possible).

So far, i was thinking about this approach:

```
big_res = []
for r in xrange(len(a2)):
    big_indices = np.argwhere(a1 == a2[r])
    small_res = []
    for k in xrange(2):
        small_indices = [i for i in a2[r] if i in a1[big_indices[k]]]
        np.append(small_res, small_indices)
    combined_res = [[big_indices[0],small_res[0]],[big_indices[1],small_res[1]]]
    np.append(big_res, combined_res)
```

Comment: What about shape[1]? Do they always have size 3/4?

Comment: a1.shape = (1000000,4) and a2.shape = (10000,3)

Comment: Also; do you have any expectations wrt the shape of results? Will there tend to be a limited number of matches or may they grow quadratically with the length of a1 and a2?

Comment: the result has the size of 10k * 2 * 3 (10k rows of a2, a2 appears twice in a1, 3 values stored for position in a1). So the end result grows linearly with size of a2

Comment: Is a2 free of duplicate rows?

Comment: yes it is free of duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Using [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP), (disclaimer: I am its author) what I think of as the hard part can be written efficiently as follows:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi

a1s = np.sort(a1, axis=1)
a2s = np.sort(a2, axis=1)
matches = np.array([npi.indices(a2s, np.delete(a1s, i, axis=1), missing=-1) for i in range(4)])
rows, cols = np.argwhere(matches != -1).T
a1idx = cols
a2idx = matches[rows, cols]
# results.shape = [len(a2), 2]
result = npi.group_by(a2idx).split_array_as_array(a1idx)
```

This only gives you the matches efficiently; not the relative orders. But once you have the matches, computing the relative orders should be simple to do in linear time.

EDIT: and some code of questionable density to get your relative orderings:

```
order = npi.indices(
    (np.indices(a1.shape)[0].flatten(), a1.flatten()),
    (np.repeat(result.flatten(), 3),    np.repeat(a2, 2, axis=0).flatten())
).reshape(-1, 2, 3) - result[..., None] * 4
```

Comment: is there any work around to not sort a1? this ndarray can be really huge (minimum 1Mio rows up to roughly 400Mio) and I would rather keep the structure.

Comment: You mean you dont want the sort to make a copy for memory reasons? Sorting along that short axis is the least of your problems, performance-wise. But as general advice if memory constraints are your problem you probably should not be using numpy, since there usually is no way around a healthy dose of temporaries. Your problem would probably also map reasonably well to numba.

Comment: As for memory tricks: if your numbers are always small, for instance always 0-9 integers, you can first pack your 3-tuples into 16-bit integers before doing the matching. That said it only saves you a factor two assuming they were already stored as 8bit ints. Also you should eliminate the np.array call then for sure, and act on the individual rows of `matches` without forming the entire array first.